# PROBLEM: Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-studio, dart

**I have a problem, when I try to run my application on a mobile phone the installation does not work, after 20 minutes the app does not install on the mobile. I didn't have this problem until today, how can I solve it?**

Launching lib/main.dart on ONEPLUS A6013 in debug mode...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.

Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...

**it has been standing on the last line for 20 minutes**

Comment: try with `flutter clean` .
Maybe it is downloading something/tools on background, you can monitor your network activity or task activity from task manager.

Answer (score 0):

Change the applicationId in **android\app\build.gradle** file like this:

from :

```
    defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId "com.xxxxxxxxxxx.yyyyyy1"
}
```

to :

```
defaultConfig {
                // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
                applicationId "com.xxxxxxxxxxx.yyyyyy2"
    }
```